# EF6 - Carga apressada trazendo menos dados agregados que os dados do banco

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Estou tendo o seguinte problema com meus relacionamentos no Entity.
Quando eu busco por exemplo um Cliente do banco pelo Id :

```
return _databaseContext.Clientes
                               .Include(x => x.Enderecos)
                               .Include(x => x.Documentos)
                               .Include(x => x.Telefones)
                               .SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
```

Ele possui 2 Enderecos, 2 Documentos e 3 Telefones.
Mas o Entity só traz 1 documento, 1 endereco e 2 telefones. :

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não consigo entender o motivo. Até usando o LazyLoad ele não carrega, fora que ele está gerando uma *query* extremamente enorme e mal feita com vários Unions e SubSelects. Alguém tem alguma idéia?

Vou colocar apenas algumas props pois a classe é enorme:

```
public class ClienteEntity : Entity<int>
{
    private IList<EnderecoClienteEntity> _enderecos;

    public ClienteEntity(string nome,
        IList<EnderecoClienteEntity> enderecos)
    {
        Nome = nome;


        _enderecos = new List<EnderecoClienteEntity>();
        enderecos.ToList().ForEach(endereco => AddEndereco(endereco));
    }

    public string Nome { get; private set; }


    public virtual ICollection<EnderecoClienteEntity> Enderecos
    {
        get { return _enderecos; }
        private set { _enderecos = new List<EnderecoClienteEntity>(value); }
    }

    public void AddEndereco(EnderecoClienteEntity endereco)
    {
        if(endereco.CriarEndereco())
            _enderecos.Add(endereco);
    }
}
```

Descobri aqui onde está o erro, ele está na lista:

```
public virtual ICollection<EnderecoClienteEntity> Enderecos { get; set; }
  //  {
  //      get { return _enderecos; }
  //      private set { _enderecos = new List<EnderecoClienteEntity>(value);    }
  //   }
```

Se eu deixar a lista assim, ele traz tudo que tem no relacionamento. Mas qual seria o motivo?

Comment: Como estão os dados no banco?

Comment: Tem como colocar as suas classes ?

Comment: Opa, blz Cigano? Está normal fazendo o relacionamento one-to-many e mapeando a ClienteId nas tabelas Endereco, Telefone e Documento.
Os dados já estão no banco e inclusive se eu rodar o select que aparece no output quando uso lazyload está certinha. Porém ela não traz todos os objetos relacionados, apenas alguns.

Comment: Atualizado, coloquei as query gerada também.

Comment: Sim, mas eu preciso de um exemplo. Por exemplo, ClienteId 1, Endereços 2 e 3, Documentos 4 e 5, Telefones 6, 7 e 8.

Comment: Você quer ver os dados que estão no banco?

Comment: Isso. Aparentemente, não há nada de errado com a consulta. Está otimizada, inclusive.

Comment: O que é `endereco.CriarEndereco()`? Qual a necessidade disso?

Comment: Descobri o motivo do erro, se eu tirar o meu get e private set e colocar apenas {get; set;} ele traz tudo do relacionamento. Teria como arrumar sem usar tudo publico?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Todo este código é inútil:

```
public ClienteEntity(string nome,
    IList<EnderecoClienteEntity> enderecos)
{
    Nome = nome;

    _enderecos = new List<EnderecoClienteEntity>();
    enderecos.ToList().ForEach(endereco => AddEndereco(endereco));
}

public virtual ICollection<EnderecoClienteEntity> Enderecos
{
    get { return _enderecos; }
    private set { _enderecos = new List<EnderecoClienteEntity>(value); }
}

public void AddEndereco(EnderecoClienteEntity endereco)
{
    if(endereco.CriarEndereco())
        _enderecos.Add(endereco);
}
```

Simplifique este para:

```
public virtual ICollection<EnderecoClienteEntity> Enderecos { get; set; }
```

Não é você que tem manipular as entidades agregadas e os níveis de proteção. É o Entity Framework que faz isso. Apenas deixe o *framework* trabalhar por você e não se preocupe tanto com segurança de código.

Comment: Eu utilizo assim porcausa da classe scope que válida as informações do campo da entidade endereço por exemplo. Se estiver tudo certo eu adiciono na lista na entidade. Outro motivo de eu usar assim é pra impedir do lado de fora da classe cliente.Enderecos.Add(endereco). Vc acha que msm assim não vale a pena manter?

Comment: Assim você está "impedindo do lado de fora" também o *Controller* de manipular a propriedade, o que é absolutamente normal no MVC. Não vale a pena manter.

Comment: Estou usando DDD e tentei aplicar o conceito de modelo rico que vi em um curso. Vi que na prop da lista vc tirou o private do set. Isso só se aplica as listas ou nas outras props tbem?  Esse controller que vc falou que manipula a propriedade e do mvc ou do entity framework?

Comment: Você precisa fazer **urgentemente** meu curso. Não use DDD. Só vai te atrapalhar.

Comment: Vou te chamar lá no face pra gente conversa sobre o curso que agora fiquei curioso rsrs. Enfim mto obrigado pela sua ajuda aqui mano. Um abraço!